# В чём состоят обязанности менеджера сообщества и каковы его права?

Tags: поддержка

Сегодня столкнулся с ситуацией, когда один из участников сайта в обсуждении с менеджером сообщества пытался донести до КМ мысль, что "хороший менеджер сообщества на мой взгляд должен делать то-то", на что получал ответ вида "у меня есть работодатель и он определяет мои обязанности".

Из этого разговора я не очень понял, в чём состоят обязанности менеджера сообщества, а поискав в справке и на мете не нашёл подобных тем.

Поскольку вопросы на мете нельзя адресовать какому-то конкретному участнику -- я адресую его всем: в чём состоят обязанности (ну и уж чтобы два раза не вставать: и права) менеджера сообщества? Я не имею ввиду такие же гипотетические ответы "я считаю, что хороший менеджер сообщества должен делать то-то". Я подозреваю, что где-то могут быть регламентирующие документы, возможно не на русском языке. Не видел кто?

Было неплохо услышать также и KPI по которым оценивается деятельность КМ, но мне кажется, тут будет очень тесная привязка к финансам, поэтому вряд ли такое будет в публичном доступе.

Метки на вопросе не знаю какие ставить, пусть будет "поддержка".

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-team-and-what-do-they-do

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Перевод ответа из вопроса: [Who is on the Community Management Team, and what do they do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-team-and-what-do-they-do)</sub>

### Кто такие управляющие сообществами?

#### [Nicolas Chabanovsky](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/274323/nicolas-chabanovsky)

[image: Network flair for Nicolas]

#### [Juan M](https://stackexchange.com/users/6254215/juan-m)

[image: Network flair for Juan M]

#### [JNat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/208518/jnat)

[image: Network flair for JNat]

#### [Catija](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/284336/catija)

[image: Network flair for Catija]

#### [Cesar M](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/508266/cesar-m)

[image: Network flair for Cesar M]

### Что они делают?

Помогают вам! Хотя, не совсем напрямую. Помогают по основным вопросам, не касающихся тематики основного сайта.

Анализируют заявки на новые сайты на [Зоне 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), просматривают, выявляют проблемные места, закрывают, удаляют и готовят сайты к запуску, в зависимости от того, чего требует ситуация.

Модерируют только что запущенные сайты, отвечают на вопросы о их развитии, пытаясь передать опыт, который был получен за время запуска сайтов Сети. Назначают [временных](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) модераторов, отдавая им управление сайтами.

Управляющие сообществами — это верхушка айсберга администрации Stack Exchange, которая всегда видна.

Следят за множеством различных Мета-сайтов, отвечают на вопросы, адресуют или эскалируют запросы и делятся опытом по использованию всего спектра возможностей движка.

Еще они иногда отвечают по почте!

Анализируют активность модераторов, предлагают им свою помощь, разрешают споры.

А затем они засыпают. Оставляя один глаз открытым. Как птицы.

### И [Дух сообщества](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community)  с ними?

Нет. Дух — [это особый участник](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%94%D1%83%D1%85+%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0), у которого есть своя метка [дух-сообщества](/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0).

Comment: Как же вы хвалите Управляющих Сообществами! Наверное, очень хорошие люди.

Comment: Было бы интереснее увидеть свою точку зрения, а не перевод ответа с MSE, несмотря на то, что точки зрения и могут совпадать. Кстати, почему-то тут даже нет фразы "свободный перевод", как это бывало ранее.

Comment: @alexolut, судя по всему, на этот раз перевод точный, а не свободный?

Comment: @Qwertiy а оригинальный ответ можно считать за официальный? Или там опять солянка из мнений?

Comment: @Suvitruf, а вот тут не скажу, но можно заглянуть в историю его правок.

Comment: @Qwertiy там общий ответ, который правили 28 пользователей...

Comment: @Suvitruf, текст написан в [6й резизии](//meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/99341/6) Шогом и практически (а то и совсем) не менялся. Остальные действия - процентов 90 - изменение списка участников и правки опечаток.