# Как в локализованных сообществах заранее узнавать о нововведениях в сети SE?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, перевод-содержимого

Я хотел бы поднять следующую проблему.

Насколько я вижу, на локализованных сайтах не организовано уведомление о предстоящих изменениях движка. Считается, что раз есть тема на [метамете](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) — то все могут зайти туда и прочитать.

Подозреваю, что заранее на метамету не часто ходят и англоязычные сообщества, типа какой-нибудь [TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) или [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/) — и только если новая функциональность непонятна или не нравится — тогда и вылезают. Ещё острее проблема стоит у локализованных сообществ — там добавляется ещё и языковой барьер.

Из последних примеров вспоминается CoC, когда [КМ пригласил нас к обсуждению за день до окончания обсуждения на метамете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7633/213987) (а перевод добровольцы завершили позже) и [обновление "с ладошками"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314287/348096) — о котором тоже нет каких-то тем на русской мете, кроме [разве что "вот тут непереведённая строка"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7704/213987).

Я не хочу спрашивать, входит ли это в обязанности модераторов или [менеджера сообщества](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7652/213987), мы это проходили и получается так, что никто это не обязан делать.

У меня тогда три вопроса:

- видит ли управляющая компания в этом проблему, что люди узнают о нововведениях с запаздыванием (что ведёт к дополнительному, зряшному негативу)?
- как устроен текущий процесс информирования на метамете и в локализованных сообществах, может быть есть какой-то специальный тег типа new-feature для "будущие изменения в сети SE"?
- можно ли как-то улучшить данный процесс уведомлений участников о нововведениях (например, вместо постинга во вконтактик переводить заранее посты по определённым меткам метаметы)?

Comment: Вопросы в меткой [meta-tag:важное] с метаметы показываются в важном по всей сети.

Comment: О ... узнал новое слово "зряшный".

Answer (score 5):

Конечно, подобный перевод и информирование, будет не лишним, особенно заранее. Но проблема мне видится гораздо глубже и несколько иного рода.

### "Тихие" изменения

Иногда, компания Stack Exchange делает изменения и нигде об этом не пишет и не спрашивает. К примеру, не так давно на всех сайтах избранные метки стали [сортироваться по алфавиту](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310294/346987) и никто об этом никого не информировал, просто пользователи увидели это по факту. То есть даже без локализации, нигде об этом не было написано ни слова. Не знаю, насколько часто компания так делает и какова значимость подобных "тихих" изменений, просто я не каждый раз об этом куда-то писал или не видел в этом смысла.

### Игнорирование обратной связи

Тут взять к примеру, [недавние "замечательные" изменения в навигационном меню](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310908/346987). Было уведомления через главную мету, пост собрал на момент написания почти -200, но изменения так и оставили в силе, пофиксив пару косметических багов. На мете упомянутого ТеX было 2 самых отрицательных по рейтингу поста: один — [до изменений](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7743/162228), второй — [по факту](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7781/162228). Причательно, что на мете того сайта вообще крайне мало постов с отрицательным рейтингом (6 из 1922 на момент написания!). Участники просили одного — не вносить данных изменений. Надо признаться, что частично вернули "как было", но сайт всё равно лишился настолько удивительного и самобытного дизайна, каким он был раньше. На математике тоже [изменения совсем не пришлись по душе сообществу](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28842), но это ничего не поменяло. Это один из ярчайших и свежих примеров, которых немало, когда воля компании идёт наперекор большинству пользотелей. Лично я не вижу много смысла в информировании, когда ничего нельзя поменять.

### Code of Conduct — это не изменения

> Из последних примеров вспоминается CoC

Code of Conduct АКА "Нормы поведения" не поменяли ничего. Вообще. Даже недавний пост [про запрет иронии](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7593/220571) был вызван просто непониманием его текста — подшучивания и раньше не одобрялись и всё делалось модераторами по их усмотрению, а в случае недовольства можно было, как и сейчас, писать на мете и/или в обратной связи для сотрудников компании.

### Когда именно узнавать об обновления — неужели это важно?

> люди узнают о нововведениях с запаздыванием (что ведёт к дополнительному, зряшному негативу)

Хочу сказать о том, что у меня некоторые фичи вызывают негатив вне зависимости от того, когда об этом узнаю — по факту или заранее.

Узнавать по факту — может кому-то неприятней, что заранее. Лично для меня одинаково, так как если изменения хороши, то вряд ли я ускорю этот процесс внедрения, если неприятны — то очень не факт, что смогу убедить их не вносить. То есть то, что очень мал шанс что-то поменять вызывает больше обеспокоенности, чем время информирования.

А вот оспорить всегда можно даже по факту. Причём совершенно бессрочно. Если вдруг у кого-то есть аргументы почему что-то в новой функциональности надо поменять или вернуть "как было", то об этом можно писать совершенно в любое время. Обсуждать новые изменения можно без срока давности. И точно также вашу обратную связь могут проигнорировать, как и до внедрения, так и несколько лет спустя, вне зависимости от популярности вашей идеи.

Answer (score 2):

Я задал на MSE вопрос именно про локалицации: [How localized sites could translate strings before update actually rolled out?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314599/260198)

Не думаю, правда, что внятный ответ получим. Странно, что я там похожих вопросов не нашёл.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я могу судить, оригинальные строки в transifex попадают в момент выкатки обновления.

Как минимум, строки по последнему обновлению с ладошками появились в системе лишь 21 числа. Так что, как я понимаю, заранее это дело не перевести.